# Nested List as a Parameter in WCF web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF method which have a nested List parameter, like this

```
public void Method(List<class1> class1Obj, List<List<SomeClass>> someClassObj)
{
  // CODE
}
```

After setting service reference I get this in my client reference method through which I can call my WCF method

```
public void Method(class1[] class1Obj, SomeClass[][] someClassObj) 
{
    base.Channel.Method(class1Obj, someClassObj);
}
```

Now to call this method from my code I can do this

```
void myServiceCaller()
{
   List<class1> class1Obj = new List<class1>();
   // Add items to class1Obj
   List<List<SomeClass>> someClassObj = List<List<SomeClass>>();
   // Add items to someClassObj

   ServiceRef.myServiceClient service = new ServiceRef.myServiceClient();
   service.Method(
               class1Obj.ToArray(), // This one is fine
               someClassObj.ToArray() // This gives me compile time error
   );  
}
```

How can I resolve this issue to convert `List<List<SomeClass>>` to `SomeClass[][]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your Service Reference and the dialog pops up you can click the **Advanced...** button in the lower left and change the **Collection type** drop-down from `System.Array` to `System.Collection.GenericList` this will then change the proxy that is created and use `List<...>` instead of `[...]` when collections are used.

In addition, if you have already added your Service Reference you can right-click on the Service Reference within the Solution tree and click **Configure Service Reference...** from the context-menu. This will show the same "Advanced" dialog mentioned above.